# Jasmine Unit Testing Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, frontend

I am using the Jasmine framework to test an angular Service which gets Data from server using `$http`

My Test is:

```
it('exists',inject(function(){

         });    
         expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();    
         expect(ctrl).not.toBeNull();
         expect(typeof ctrl).toBe('object');
}));
```

Are there other tests I can perform on this service like:

1. checking the data format returned by server or
2. testing the duration of the call?

Comment: I think we need more information to help.  I tried to edit the best I could, but I'm not sure that your question is clear even now.

Comment: If we have an angular Service witch provide data from server using $http in this service we have 2 function one for getting data(json) let's say getList and the second one is for updating list row I want to know wich kind of unit test can I perform to test this angular Service. All what I do is testing the esxisting of those 2 function and checking the parameter of each function